# Serialização de listas em classes C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialização, lista

Boa tarde pessoal, estou realizando um projeto de NFe para emissão, logo optei, depois de pesquisar usar serialização de classes para montar o xml. Tudo funciona muito bem, a partir de uma estrutura de classe que defini monto o xml, porém em uma certa parte necessitei implementar listas em uma parte da classe para serializar, na NFe tag **det**, onde adiciono os itens da nota, montei perfeitamente a classe, funcionou, o problema é que a tag como no código abaixo não é uma lista, e não sei como instanciar ela como lista,em tentativas minhas não funcionou, porém seus childs são todas listas.

a tag  tem que ser montada dinamicamente, ex:

< det nItem="1" > ......outras tags.....< /det > < det nItem="2" >
 ......outras tags.....< /det > e assim vai.**

```
public class NFe
{
    public infNFe infNFe; 
}

public class infNFe
{

    public det det; ----------FORMA NORMAL

    public List<det> det = new List<det>(); ---------TENTEI INSTANCIAR EM LISTA

}

public class det ----------------------- ELEMENTOS ABAIXO ESTÃO EM FORMA DE LISTA
{

    [XmlAttribute("nItem")]
    public string nItem { get; set; }
    // [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    [XmlElement("prod")]
    public List<prod> prod = new List<prod>();
    //  [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    [XmlElement("imposto")]
    public imposto imposto;
    //  [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    [XmlElement("infAdProd")]
    public string infAdProd { get; set; }
}

public class prod
{
    public string cProd { get; set; }
    public string cEAN { get; set; }
    public string xProd { get; set; }
    public string NCM { get; set; }
    public string NVE { get; set; }
    public string EXTIPI { get; set; }
    public string CFOP { get; set; }
    public string uCom { get; set; }
    public string qCom { get; set; }
    public string vUnCom { get; set; }
    public string vProd { get; set; }
    public string cEANTrib { get; set; }
    public string uTrib { get; set; }
    public string qTrib { get; set; }
    public string vUnTrib { get; set; }
    public string vFrete { get; set; }
    public string vSeg { get; set; }
    public string vDesc { get; set; }
    public string vOutro { get; set; }
    public string indTot { get; set; }

    public prod() { }

    public prod(string cprod,
                string cean,
                string xprod,
                string ncm,
                string nve,
                string extipi,
                string cfop,
                string ucom,
                string qcom,
                string vuncom,
                string vprod,
                string ceantrib,
                string utrib,
                string qtrib,
                string vuntrib,
                string vfrete,
                string vseg,
                string vdesc,
                string voutro,
                string indtot)
    {

        cProd = cprod;
        cEAN = cean;
        xProd = xprod;
        NCM = ncm;
        NVE = nve;
        EXTIPI = extipi;
        CFOP = cfop;
        uCom = ucom;
        qCom = qcom;
        vUnCom = vuncom;
        vProd = vprod;
        cEANTrib = ceantrib;
        uTrib = utrib;
        qTrib = qtrib;
        vUnTrib = vuntrib;
        vFrete = vfrete;
        vSeg = vSeg;
        vDesc = vdesc;
        vOutro = voutro;
        indTot = indtot;

    }

}

public class imposto
{
    //    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public string vTotTrib;
    //  [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public ICMS ICSM;
    //   [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    public IPI IPI;
    //   [XmlElement(Order = 4)]
    public PIS PIS;
    //   [XmlElement(Order = 5)]
    public COFINS COFINS;



}

public class ICMS
{
    [XmlElement("ICMS00")]
    public List<ICMS00> ICMS00 = new List<ICMS00>();

}

public class ICMS00
{


    public string orig { get; set; }
    public string CST { get; set; }
    public string modBC { get; set; }
    public string vBC { get; set; }
    public string pICMS { get; set; }
    public string vICMS { get; set; }

    public ICMS00() { }

    public ICMS00(string orig1, string cst, string modbc, string vbc, string picms, string vicms)
    {
        orig = orig1;
        CST = cst;
        modBC = modbc;
        vBC = vbc;
        pICMS = picms;
        vICMS = vicms;
    }

}

public class IPI
{
    // [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public string cEnq { get; set; }
    // [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    [XmlElement("IPINT")]
    public List<IPINT> IPINT = new List<IPINT>();

}

public class IPINT
{

    public string CST { get; set; }

    public IPINT() { }

    public IPINT(string cst)
    {
        CST = cst;
    }

}



public class PIS
{
    [XmlElement("PISOutr")]
    public List<PISOutr> PISOutr = new List<PISOutr>();
    [XmlElement("PISAliq")]
    public List<PISAliq> PISAliq = new List<PISAliq>();

}



public class PISOutr
{

    public string CST { get; set; }
    public string vBC { get; set; }
    public string pPIS { get; set; }
    public string vPIS { get; set; }

    public PISOutr() { }

    public PISOutr(string cst, string vbc, string ppis, string vpis)
    {
        CST = cst;
        vBC = vbc;
        pPIS = ppis;
        vPIS = vpis;

    }

}


public class PISAliq
{

    public string CST { get; set; }
    public string vBC { get; set; }
    public string pPIS { get; set; }
    public string vPIS { get; set; }

    public PISAliq() { }

    public PISAliq(string cst, string vbc, string ppis, string vpis)
    {
        CST = cst;
        vBC = vBC;
        pPIS = ppis;
        vPIS = vpis;
    }

}




public class COFINS
{
    [XmlElement("COFINSOutr")]
    public List<COFINSOutr> COFINSOutr = new List<COFINSOutr>();
    [XmlElement("COFINSAliq")]
    public List<COFINSAliq> COFINSAliq = new List<COFINSAliq>();

}

public class COFINSOutr
{


    public string CST { get; set; }
    public string vBC { get; set; }
    public string pCOFINS { get; set; }
    public string vCOFINS { get; set; }

    public COFINSOutr() { }

    public COFINSOutr(string cst, string vbc, string pcofins, string vcofins)
    {
        CST = cst;
        vBC = vbc;
        pCOFINS = pcofins;
        vCOFINS = vcofins;
    }

}


public class COFINSAliq
{

    public string CST { get; set; }
    public string vBC { get; set; }
    public string pCOFINS { get; set; }
    public string vCOFINS { get; set; }

    public COFINSAliq() { }

    public COFINSAliq(string cst, string vbc, string pcofins, string vcofins)
    {

        CST = cst;
        vBC = vbc;
        pCOFINS = pcofins;
        vCOFINS = vcofins;

    }

}

CLASSE INSTANCIADA PARA SERIALIZAR
```

Usei um laço de repetição na instancias abaixo

```
for(int item = 0; item <= 2 ;item++){  
    nfe.infNFe.det = new det();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.nItem = item.ToString();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.prod.Add(new prod(item.ToString(), "SASASASA", "sasasa", "SASASASASAS", "SSASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASAS", "SASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASASA", "SASASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASASA", "SASASASA", "SAS", "SASASAS"));
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto = new imposto();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.vTotTrib = "BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA";
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.ICSM = new ICMS();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.ICSM.ICMS00.Add(new ICMS00("SASASASASASA", "SASASASASAS", "SASASASAS", "SASASASASA", "SASASASAS", "ASASASASA"));
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.IPI = new IPI();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.IPI.cEnq = "SASASASA";
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.IPI.IPINT.Add(new IPINT(""));
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.PIS = new PIS();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.PIS.PISAliq.Add(new PISAliq("SASASASASA", "SASASASASA", "SASASASASA", "SASASASASA"));
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.PIS.PISOutr.Add(new PISOutr("ASASASASASA", "ASASASASASA", "ASASASASASA", "SASASASASA"));
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.COFINS = new COFINS();
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.COFINS.COFINSAliq.Add(new COFINSAliq("SASASASA", "SASASASA", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS"));
                   nfe.infNFe.det.imposto.COFINS.COFINSOutr.Add(new COFINSOutr("SASASASAS", "ASASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASA"));

}
```

Porém o resultado da serialização das listas é apenas a ultima iteração  no laço for.

Lembrando que estou serializando a classe NFe por completo.

caso eu tente serializar apenas a classe  funciona.

Resumindo como transformo a classe  uma lista e instancio ela, sendo que seus childs também são listas.

Comment: Você gerou como a sua classe de NFe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente desta maneira

```
public sealed class NFe
{
    public infNFe infNFe;
}

public sealed class infNFe
{
    private List<det> _dets;
    public det[] det { 
         get { return _dets.toArray(); } //pegamos a variável privada que é uma lista e convertemos ela para array na hora de serializar (ou quando se acessa esta propriedade - det)
         set { _dets = value.toList(); } //supondo que você receba um array de dets, convertemos ele para lista e armazenamos na variável privada.
    }
    //Se você utilizar lista provavelmente terá problemas na serialização XML, dependendo de como esta sendo feita essa serialização, então vamos usar um array primitivo.

    public infNFe(){
       _dets = new List<det>();
    }

    public Add(det det)
    {
       _dets.add(det);
    }
}
```

Ai no seu loop, faça o seguinte:

```
 nfe.infNFe = new infNfe();
 for(int item = 0; item <= 2 ;item++){  
    var atual = new det();
    atual.nItem = item.ToString();
    atual.nItem.prod.Add(new prod(item.ToString(), "SASASASA", "sasasa", "SASASASASAS", "SSASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASAS", "SASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASASA", "SASASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS", "SASASASASA", "SASASASA", "SAS", "SASASAS"));
    atual.nItem.imposto = new imposto();
    atual.nItem.imposto.vTotTrib = "BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA";
    atual.nItem.imposto.ICSM = new ICMS();
    atual.nItem.imposto.ICSM.ICMS00.Add(new ICMS00("SASASASASASA", "SASASASASAS", "SASASASAS", "SASASASASA", "SASASASAS", "ASASASASA"));
    atual.nItem.imposto.IPI = new IPI();
    atual.nItem.imposto.IPI.cEnq = "SASASASA";
    atual.nItem.imposto.IPI.IPINT.Add(new IPINT(""));
    atual.nItem.imposto.PIS = new PIS();
    atual.nItem.imposto.PIS.PISAliq.Add(new PISAliq("SASASASASA", "SASASASASA", "SASASASASA", "SASASASASA"));
    atual.nItem.imposto.PIS.PISOutr.Add(new PISOutr("ASASASASASA", "ASASASASASA", "ASASASASASA", "SASASASASA"));
    atual.nItem.imposto.COFINS = new COFINS();
    atual.nItem.imposto.COFINS.COFINSAliq.Add(new COFINSAliq("SASASASA", "SASASASA", "SASASASA", "SASASASAS"));
    atual.nItem.imposto.COFINS.COFINSOutr.Add(new COFINSOutr("SASASASAS", "ASASASASAS", "SASASASA", "SASASASA"));


    //aqui está a mágica
    nfe.infNFe.add(atual); //aqui você usa o método add da class infNfe que criamos previamente e com isso teremos a lista de "det"s populada
}
```

Comment: Guilherme, funcionou perfeitamente bem, legar o array e depois add a list, só alterei poucas coisas [XmlElement("det")]
        public List<det> dets;


        public infNFe()
        {
            dets = new List<det>();
        }

         public void adicionar(det det){
            dets.Add(det);
            
        }, retirei  a instancia nfe.infNFe = new infNfe();, pois no inicio do cod já tinha instanciado, e retirei nItem, montou diretamente a NFe com os itens de forma dinâmica, muito obrigado pela ajuda, tenho que pegar os dados do banco agora vlw.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou! Abrç!